# Recalling a function

Tags: java, android, admob

I have this boolean defined in a class:

```
private boolean showad;
```

I have this function defined in the same class, which checks if `showad` is set to `true`:

```
public void adon() {
  if (showad == true) {
    AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.ad);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
  }
}
```

How do I get this function `adon()` to run repeatedly in order to check changes in the `showad` boolean?

Comment: Surely you have some code which sets `showad` - so you can call it there, instead of "constantly".

Comment: showad is `boolean`  not `String`!

Comment: Get used to using `if (showad)` instead of `if (showad == true)`. It's redundant.

Comment: why do you want this to run constantly? ou could call adon in a while(1) loop, though that is not likely what you want since it will eat up all your CPU. otherwise you might need to set up a timer.

Comment: But when I call adon() in the WebAppInterface(JS Interface) the app crashes

Answer (score 4):

Ok I'm going to go on a limb here and guess that you dont really actually want an infinite loop to check your boolean to show an ad. So let me give you some real advice, instead of flaming in the comments. It seems that you want to check whether or not to show an ad on a certain screen: activity or fragment.

So my advice to you is:

Put that if condition check in your onResume() method, and show/don't show your ad there.

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
            if (showad == true) {
                  AdView AdView = (AdView) this.findViewById (R.id.ad);
                  adView.loadAd (AdRequest new ());
            }
}
```

This way it will check whenever your screen is loaded/refreshed. I'm thinking you dont really want a real time check of whether to show your ad anyways, as that is pretty jarring to the user. Just check it in onResume(). If you have any further questions leave a comment and I will expand my answer. If you like the answer, please upvote and accept.

But if it really must be real time. I can help you set up a timer/delay runnable that will check every once in a while.

Answer (score 3):

```
void setShowad(boolean val) {
    if (showad) {
        AdView AdView = (AdView) this.findViewById (R.id.ad);
        adView.loadAd (AdRequest new ());
    }
    showad = val;
}
```